# Pyspark Combine Columns in different rows to a single row order by another Column

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-notebooks

[image]

I have a dataframe which have 2 Columns CLMN_SEQ_NUM and CLMN_NM. I am tryng to combine the Columns CLMN_NM to a single row comma separated.

Desired o/p
PR_NAME,PR_ID,PR_ZIP,PR_ADDRESS,PR_COUNTRY

```
cols_comb = df.agg(F.concat_ws(",",F.collect_list(F.col("CLMN_NM")))).first()[0]
```

But the order is coming differently
PR_ZIP,PR_NAME,PR_COUNTRY,PR_ID,PR_ADDRESS as to not how its in the dataframe.

How can I combine the columns to be ordered by CLMN_SEQ_NUM

Answer (score 0):

Pack `CLMN_NM` and `CLMN_SEQ_NUM` into struct then aggregate the dataframe to collect all the structs and sort

```
L = df.agg(F.collect_list(F.struct('CLMN_SEQ_NUM', 'CLMN_NM'))).first()[0]
cols = [r.CLMN_NM for r in sorted(L)]
```

---

```
# cols
['PR_NAME', 'PR_ZIP', 'PR_ADDRESS', 'PR_COUNTRY', 'PR_ID']
```